# Fetch directly to mounted IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb, emscripten

From Enscripten C code, is it possible to download directly to IndexedDB that is mounted to the local filesystem? I managed to download the file directly to IndexedDB, and I managed to mount IndexedDB to the filesystem, but they are different databases. Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying?

The use case is this:

- I want to download a remote web resource
- Once download is complete, I want to be able to fopen() it
- I want to changes written to the file from C code to be persisted between reloads
- Ideally, all this without having to load the entire file in memory

It feels like this should be a fairly common use case but I keep banging my head against a wall trying to find documentation on this.